# Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk and <EnableComHosting>true</EnableComHosting> for COM interop - mutually exclusive?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, com, xunit

I am working on a Solidworks add-in for running integration tests within Solidworks; upgrading from net48 to net5.

I am handling AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve to locate my test assembly:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += runner.ResolveAssembly
```

So far so good. Unfortunately, attempting to discover tests:

```
using var runner = AssemblyRunner.WithoutAppDomain(_assemblyPath);
runner.OnDiscoveryComplete = info => _log($"{Environment.Version} Discovered {info.TestCasesDiscovered} test cases.");
```

Returns 0 tests, and an error in the test output window:

```
========== Starting test discovery ==========
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException: Unable to find C:\Users\jon\source\repos\SWCustomPropertyTest\SWCustomPropertyTest\bin\Debug\net5.0-windows\testhost.dll. Please publish your test project and retry.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager.GetTestHostPath(String runtimeConfigDevPath, String depsFilePath, String sourceDirectory)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager.GetTestHostProcessStartInfo(IEnumerable`1 sources, IDictionary`2 environmentVariables, TestRunnerConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel(IEnumerable`1 sources, String runSettings)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyDiscoveryManager.DiscoverTests(DiscoveryCriteria discoveryCriteria, ITestDiscoveryEventsHandler2 eventHandler)
========== Test discovery aborted: 0 Tests found in 9.7 ms ==========
```

This makes sense; testhost.dll doesn't exist in my output because I don't have a reference to Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk in my project. However, when I add a reference to Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk and rebuild, the output folder no longer contains a .comhost.dll to register.

I tried simply copying testhost.dll to my output folder but when I did this and tried to execute my code again the output window stayed blank and debug output indicated that I had discovered 0 tests.

Are `<EnableComHosting>true</EnableComHosting>` and Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk mutually exclusive? Is there a way to discover and execute a unit test from within a COM add-in, in .NET 5?

Comment: It should be.  Testing a [ComVisible] server with .NET code is not useful, it doesn't test the COM interface.  [This programmer](https://github.com/weianweigan/SldWorks.TestRunner) knew that.

Comment: I'm not testing the COM DLL. I am using the COM DLL to execute integration tests within the Solidworks add-in framework, but I can't find a way to make test discovery work. If I add Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk nuget package to my project references, building the project will no longer generate a .comhost.dll file. I need both!

Comment: The programmer who created that project was doing something very similar, but he is using .NET Framework. My test runner works in .NET Framework, too. It just doesn't work in NET Core. The challenge I'm running into is that I cannot get both .comhost.dll and testhost.dll in my output folder. When I add the test SDK to my NET 5 project it seems to disable generation of the comhost DLL.